# Create new array for average of previous 7 slices of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've converted a NetCDF to a numpy array (x,y,z) where x = time.  Over the past 7x I need to get the average at each y,z location and store it in a new array.

Example:array(2,2,2)

```
array([[[1,2],
        [2,3]],

        [[4,5],
        [7,9]]])
```

At each step in time (x)  I need to average the past 7 days for every y,z option and store it in a new matrix.  so in the above example x=0 would just be `[[1,2],[2,3]]` because you can't step back in time, but x=1 would be the average of `[[1&4,2&5],[2&7,3&9]]`.

If the array x is <7 than I just want to average whatever I can grab previous to that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple, and explicit solution, although probably not the most performant, is:

```
[np.mean(a[max(i-6, 0):i+1,:], axis=0) for i in xrange(len(a))]
```

you'll get a list of numpy arrays where each array is the average matrix for the day at the index and the 6 prior

Comment: That does work correctly.  Thank you for the answer.  I'll be using the output in a function where I have to multiply different matrices of the same size.  I'm still wrapping my head around how reshaping works but I'm guessing you can use reshape to turn that list of arrays into the same format of the original matrix.

Comment: I set your solution to b then used 
np.reshape(b,(a.shape))

Comment: newArray = np.reshape([np.mean(a[max(i-6, 0):i+1,:], axis=0) for i in xrange(len(a))],(a.shape))

Comment: I think you don't even need np.reshape, just use np.array; it should already have the right shape.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
a = np.array([[[1,2],
               [2,3]],
              [[4,5],
               [7,9]]])

print a.mean(axis=0)

# array([[2.5, 3.5],
#        [4.5, 6.]])
```

Comment: I'm sorry.  My explanation was not thorough enough and quite confusing.  I'm going to edit the question to make it mor eclear.

Comment: Hopefully the edit makes more sense.  If x=7 I need to average every y,z location from x=1 to x=7.  If x = 10 I need to average every y,z location from x=4 to x=10.